# strange ForkJoinPool behaviour

Tags: java, concurrency, java-8, threadpool

Java8 stream and parallel stream use `ForkJoinPool.commonPool` which is a general purpose pool (that theoretically keeps as many threads as CPUs there are on the machine) for short tasks...

I'm using some java8 features and i noticed that pool keeps only one thread and constantly kills and replaces it...

[image]

if I choose to see only live threads i'll have only one thread in the pool...

[image]

**So the question is why does the pool replace the thread all the time? why not reuse it? Is this a normal behaviour? (if so, why?)**

Comment: Can you offer us a test case we can run ourselves?

Comment: This is seen on an enterprize piece of code, i'll try to isolate the issue... 
but you never saw such behaviour? i mean i have no way to influence what the common pool does... how could my code possibly do anything with it...

Comment: I would imagine it is the FJ pool doing it and not your code, but it's hard to tell based on only the description of the problem.

Comment: That being said, I would assume the FJ pool is re-creating it for a reason and I doubt it will aggressively be creating new threads very often, at least by default.

Comment: My guess is that you are only submitting enough tasks for one thread to be busy.  You should know that the FJ pool will use threads when it needs to and kill threads that are not being used.

Comment: Yes kill it but in few seconds? it is doing it like in 10 seconds... you can see in diagram... in source i can see that core thread count is 0, that means that its perfectly fine for it to have 0 threads (for example when i dont use stream)... anyway i clearly see that wait time is 60 seconds... in source code

Comment: Unfortunately this is a piece of code i'm not able to isolate right now but i'll definitely digg into this tomorrow and post the results here... I hoped someone already had this situation...

Comment: Please add the original image back, it gave a clear view of a repeating cycle

Answer (score 2):

I don't think your deduction is correct. The pool has X number of threads. Let's say it starts with 5 threads. Now there will be 5 threads in IDLE state. If you hand it work, it will put 1 thread into ACTIVE state and then once the work is complete, it goes back to IDLE. If the pool is backed by a Queue, the thread pulled first is Thread0, then that goes to the back of the pool, the pool uses the other 4 threads and only then will Thread0 be used again. This is the pattern it is showing in your graph.
Probably the reason you see only 1 thread live is that your work is so short that the Thread completes and goes back to IDLE before the next thread starts.

**Edit**

From the [code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.java#3332):
It creates a LIFO queue, with 1 thread if other properties/number of cores cannot be determined. Depending on how you startup your application, it might lead to some unexpected behavior, but cannot be sure of that since I have no idea about your system or application. The answer above is just explaining the way thread pools work and the pattern you showed in your first image can be understood based on this explanation.

Comment: So according to that threads in IDLE are not shown in yourkit? i think they show up, anyway why should they filter out when i choose "show only life threads" ...

Comment: I've not used the tool so I'm not familiar with the interface, but it looks like the different lines are based on some kind of pattern (maybe new tasks to each thread), but the thread name is the same. If it was killing and starting a new thread, it should increment the counter; so you would get as many threads as the number of tasks you submit.

Comment: No i'm pretty sure each line is a single thread, i've updated for you the screenshots...

Comment: I see like it creates thread it waits in IDLE for few seconds and dies then other thread replaces it... thats why you have 10 worker-0s etc...

Comment: The whole purpose of thread pool is not to create new threads for each small task, there could be an issue on your system, have a look at this line and the lines above to see if it is a problem on your system: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.java#3332

Comment: Well thats the exact same code that works in my jdk now, but i dont understand where the issue is?

Comment: Even I can't figure out anything unless I have more information - no code, no system details, no app config => no debug

Comment: Sure, i'll try to create a test case tomorrow :) and will give all the details

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73681/discussion-between-vach-and-tinker).